# Given the nth root of m, what are n and m called?

Tags: radicals

Very simple question:
In dividing, you have the quotient, dividend, and divisor.
When you have the $n$th root of $m$, what are the names of $n$ and $m$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the symbol $\sqrt[n]m$, $n$ is called the *index* or the *degree* of the root, $m$ the *radicand*.